# XBEE coordinator WITH or WITHOUT Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, xbee, communication

I am building a wireless system that has got an Arduino with a XBEE as the 'end user' and I need to acquire data/control that Arduino from a PC graphical interface. 
As far as I'm aware there are two options to obtain the communication:

1. I could use another Arduino with XBEE (coordinator) that is connected to my PC (serial) to control the 'end user'. The code is stored in this Arduino which works as a bypass between PC and XBEE.
2. I could simply use a XBEE without Arduino (coordinator) connected to my PC to control the 'end user'. The code should be stored within the PC or the XBEE to establish communication and control data transmission to different end users (???)

As I am new to the Arduino world, would you please direct me to the best/easiest solution to obtain such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to control and receive data from your end user, option 2 is easy to implement.

You can use any programming language that supports serial communication such as python, node.js, etc.

What you have to is to note how your coordinator is recognized by your operating system (in windows as com1 port, unix-like as ttyACM or similar) and open it from your preferred language.

After that, you establish a protocol that should be agreed with your Arduino. For example. Suppose you want to collect data from end user, so, you send a message from the coordinator connected in your PC with a code #data through the serial. When the Arduino receives it, it decodes the message and return something like #d125 where it says it is sending the data and the value is 125 (supposing integer values).

Making sure you already have configured the XBees in the same network by setting Same PAN id and cross setting the destination address of each one so they send packates to each other.

I am supposing you are using AT transparent mode where they just send whatever comes in the serial interface, in this mode they work basically sending chunks of bytes and it is up to you to establish a protocol to provide a good flow of data. In this mode there is no guarantee that your packet will reach the destination. In order to fully extend the XBee usage, you'd need the API mode where all the transmission checks are done.

But for you purpose, AT mode seems enough.